# Is $y \in\{f(x)\mid x \in X\} ⇔ f(x) \space ∃ x \in X$ true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Definition 9 $f(A) =\{f (x) \mid x\in A\}$

The following is from the proof of $f(\bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_{\gamma})$ = $\bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}f(A_{\gamma})$.

$$y \in f \left( \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_\gamma \right) \Leftrightarrow y=f(x) \text{ for some } x \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_\gamma$$

Referring to Def. 9, LHS above can denoted as $f(\bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_{\gamma})=\{f(x) \mid x \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_\gamma\}$.

Then, **$\{f(x) \mid x \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}A_\gamma\} \Leftrightarrow y=f(x)$ for some $x \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} A_\gamma$**.

[Edit] Then is the following generation of set builder notation true?

$$y \in \{f(x)\mid x \in X\} \Leftrightarrow f(x) \text{ for some } x \in X$$

Comment: No, for formal reasons: $\Leftrightarrow$ should connect two statements, but $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ is a set.

Comment: No, the last expression makes no sense: a set is not a proposition, but it's (non-)emptiness is. By the way, it's better to write $f[A]$ instead of $f(A)$, when $f: X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq X$; to distinguish the function $f$ acting on elements of a set\type $X$ and the induced function acting on (sub)sets $P(X)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How about $y \in \{f(x)| x \in X\} \Leftrightarrow f(x) \space \text{for some}\space x \in X$??

Comment: $y∈ \{ f(x) | x∈X \} ⇔ f(x)=y \text { for some } x∈X$.

Comment: No, it's not even a statement. The righthand side is ill formed: $f(x)$ is a term denoting an entity, and you can't quantify *that* (similarly, in natural language, adverbs only apply to verb phrases and not to nouns).

Comment: Use words instead of symbols you don't even know how to use.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Which part of my question is the problem with symbols?

Comment: @buzzee your statement is grammatically incorrect.  Don't use trailing quantifiers, for one thing.

Comment: @DanielV But I think I saw the author of my book using a universal quantifier at the end. Doesn't the same go for an existential quantifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I]s the following generation of set builder notation true? $$y \in \{f(x)\mid x \in X\} \Leftrightarrow f(x) \text{ for some } x \in X$$

The statement $\text{“}y \in \{f(x)\mid x \in X\}\text{''}$ is equivalent to $\text{“}y = f(x)$ for some $x\in X\text{''}$.  It's not just $\text{“}f(x)$ for some $x \in X\,\text{''}$.

$$
\Big( y\in\{f(x) \mid  x\in X\} \Big) \Longleftrightarrow \Big( (\exists\,x\in X)\ y = f(x)\Big)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The axioms of set theory (for example, ZFC) are of the form that given some set(s), the existence of another set is postulated. For most of the axioms this postulated set is *unique* (for given input sets) and therefore motivates the introduction of some *notation*. Ultimately, the meaning of these notations is determined by the predicate describing its set membership. For example (slightly simplified),

**PAIR.** If $A,B$ are sets, the pairing axiom postulates that there is a set $C$ such that 
$$ x\in C\iff x=A\lor x=B$$
We introduce the notation $\{A,B\}$ for this set $C$.

**POWER.** If $A$ is a set, the power set axiom postulates that there is a set $B$ such that $$x\in B\iff x\subseteq A$$
We introduce the notation $\mathcal P(A)$ for this set.

**SEPARATION.** Is $A$ is a set and $\Phi(x)$ a predicate with one free variable $x$, the axiom schema of separation postulates the existence of a set $B$ such that
$$x\in B\iff x\in A\land \Phi(x) $$
We introduce the notation $\{\,x\in A\mid \Phi(x)\,\}$.

**REPLACEMENT.** If $A$ is a set and $f$ a function defined on $A$, then the axiom schema of replacement postulates the existence of a set $B$ with
$$x\in B\iff \exists a\in A\colon x=f(a) $$
We introduce the notation $\{\,f(x)\mid x\in A\,\}$. As this is only a notational *convention,* we might have decided otherwise and introduce the more concise notation $f[A]$ for the same set. 
(Note that it might introduce ambiguity to use $f(A)$ instead because the domain of $f$ ma happen to contain both $x$ and $\{x\}$, in which case it is not clear what $f(\{x\})$ stands for).

In particular, we have (by the very definition of these notations)
$$\fbox{$y\in\{\,f(x)\mid x\in X\,\}\iff  \exists x\in X\colon y=f(x)$}$$

---

To elaborate, let's continue:

**UNION.** If $A$ is a set, the axiom of union postulates the existence of a set $B$ such that
$$x\in B\iff \exists a\in A\colon x\in a $$
We introduce the notation $\bigcup A$ for this set $B$.

Once we have those basic notations, we may introduce further notations for our everyday usage. For example $\{A\}:=\{A,A\}$ and $A\cup B:=\bigcup\{A,B\}$. We also introduce $\bigcup_{x\in A}f(x)$ for $\bigcup f[A]$.
With this enormous (and initially confusing) utility belt full of notation, we can make sense of
$$ \{\,f(x)\mid x\in\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}A_\gamma\,\}$$
which we might as well write as $$f\left[\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}A_\gamma\right] $$
or, using $A$ to denote the function $\gamma \mapsto A_\gamma$, even as
$$f\left[\bigcup A[\Gamma]\right]$$
We have (by the above)
$$\begin{align}y\in  \{\,f(x)\mid x\in\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}A_\gamma\,\}&\iff \exists x\in\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}A_\gamma\colon y=f(x)\\
&\iff \exists \gamma \in \Gamma\colon \exists x\in A_\gamma\colon y=f(x) \end{align} $$
Incidentally, this set $f[A[\Gamma]]$ can also be described as $\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}f[A]$ (can you see why?).